# Qué es mejor hacer antes una join y luego union o mejor union y luego join

Tags: sql, sql-server, base-de-datos, join, sql-server-2012

Tengo que hacer una `union` de 5 tablas y más tarde una `join` con una tabla con muchos registros y me gustaría saber qué es más eficiente si hacer primero la `union` de las 5 tablas y luego la `join` o mejor hacer una `join` con cada tabla con esa grande y luego hacer una `union` del resultado.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Las dos son correctas. En realidad ninguna es correcta. En realidad, el unico que sabe cual es correcta es la DB, que tiene una herramienta que se llama explain plan, y te explica cual de las dos es mejor en cada caso. Nosotros no podriamos decirte nunca cual es mejor.

Comment: Cual es tu problema?

Comment: la respuesta en general será un "depende". para un mejor análisis guíate por el plan de ejecución, puede ser un tema de acceso de datos y distinción que realiza el UNION (a diferencia del UNION ALL) o en la forma e indices con el cual realizas el JOIN o ambas, por esto mismo es mejor apoyarse en el plan de ejecución el cual te dará indicios de una mejor performance en tu consulta.

Answer (score 0):

Aunque todo lo que te han contado, es completamente cierto, a mi entender, quizá entender los planes de ejecución no sea una tarea tán fácil, como leer algo, y ya esta.
Pero puedes hacer que el motor, aun no siendo perfecto te ayude bastante a entender como lo hace más eficiente.

```
create table tabla1( id uniqueidentifier PRIMARY KEY, valor varchar(36))
create table tabla2( id uniqueidentifier PRIMARY KEY, valor varchar(36))
create table tabla3( id uniqueidentifier PRIMARY KEY, valor varchar(36))
create table tabla4( id uniqueidentifier PRIMARY KEY, valor varchar(36))
create table tabla5( id uniqueidentifier PRIMARY KEY, valor varchar(36))
go

INSERT INTO TABLA1 (ID, VALOR)
SELECT NEWID(), CAST(NEWID()AS VARCHAR(36))

INSERT INTO TABLA2(ID, VALOR)
SELECT NEWID(), CAST(NEWID()AS VARCHAR(36))

INSERT INTO TABLA3 (ID, VALOR)
SELECT NEWID(), CAST(NEWID()AS VARCHAR(36))

INSERT INTO TABLA4 (ID, VALOR)
SELECT NEWID(), CAST(NEWID()AS VARCHAR(36))

INSERT INTO TABLA5 (ID, VALOR)
SELECT NEWID(), CAST(NEWID()AS VARCHAR(36))

GO 5000
```

Hasta aquí, he creado cinco tablas con valores "aleatorios". Estas serían tus 5 pequeñas tablas, que tienen 5000 filas, cada una.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[miTablaG](
[id] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
[col1] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
[col2] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
[col3] [datetime] NOT NULL,
[col4] [int] NULL,
[col5] [float] NULL,
[col6] [int] NULL,
[col7] [float] NULL,
[col8] [int] NULL,
[col9] [float] NULL,
[col10] [int] NULL,
[col11] [float] NULL,
[col12] [int] NULL,
[col13] [float] NULL,
[col14] [int] NULL,
[col15] [float] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
CREATE table [dbo].[miTablaG2](
[id] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
[col1] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
[col2] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
[col3] [datetime] NOT NULL,
[col4] [int] NULL,
[col5] [float] NULL,
[col6] [int] NULL,
[col7] [float] NULL,
[col8] [int] NULL,
[col9] [float] NULL,
[col10] [int] NULL,
[col11] [float] NULL,
[col12] [int] NULL,
[col13] [float] NULL,
[col14] [int] NULL,
[col15] [float] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
/* el llenado lo genero de una tabla propia con 1.650.677 rows*/

select count(*) from dbo.miTablaG
/* el llenado lo genero de una tabla propia con 1.650.677 rows*/
INSERT INTO dbo.miTablaG2 
Selet * from dbo.miTablaG
GO
```

La única diferencia entre miTablaG y miTablaG2 es que G2 tiene una clave primaria (muy importante a la hora de ejecutar una consulta).

Ahora ejecuto una consulta con la union de las 5 tablas y sobre su salida (tabla derivada), la enlazo contra miTablaG y miTablaG2 posteriormente obteniendo el mismo resultado.

```
set statistics time, io on
select * from (
SELECT * FROM TABLA1
UNION 
SELECT * fROM TABLA2
UNION 
SELECT * fROM TABLA3
UNION 
SELECT * fROM TABLA4
UNION 
SELECT * fROM TABLA5
) as o
inner join dbo.miTablaG on o.id = dbo.miTablaG.id
set statistics time, io off
```

Aquí la gracia, aun no sabiendo interpretar un plan de ejecución, esta en los set Statistics time, io, que me dan info de lo que a realizado la query en función de lecturas y costes de procesamiento.

(0 filas afectadas)
Tabla 'Workfile'. Recuento de exámenes 0, lecturas lógicas 0, lecturas físicas 0, lecturas anticipadas 0, lecturas lógicas de LOB 0, lecturas físicas de LOB 0, lecturas anticipadas de LOB 0.
Tabla 'Worktable'. Recuento de exámenes 0, lecturas lógicas 0, lecturas físicas 0, lecturas anticipadas 0, lecturas lógicas de LOB 0, lecturas físicas de LOB 0, lecturas anticipadas de LOB 0.
Tabla 'miTablaG'. Recuento de exámenes 1, lecturas lógicas 28463, lecturas físicas 0, lecturas anticipadas 0, lecturas lógicas de LOB 0, lecturas físicas de LOB 0, lecturas anticipadas de LOB 0.
Tabla 'tabla5'. Recuento de exámenes 1, lecturas lógicas 64, lecturas físicas 0, lecturas anticipadas 0, lecturas lógicas de LOB 0, lecturas físicas de LOB 0, lecturas anticipadas de LOB 0.
Tabla 'tabla4'. Recuento de exámenes 1, lecturas lógicas 64, lecturas físicas 0, lecturas anticipadas 0, lecturas lógicas de LOB 0, lecturas físicas de LOB 0, lecturas anticipadas de LOB 0.
Tabla 'tabla3'. Recuento de exámenes 1, lecturas lógicas 65, lecturas físicas 0, lecturas anticipadas 0, lecturas lógicas de LOB 0, lecturas físicas de LOB 0, lecturas anticipadas de LOB 0.
Tabla 'tabla2'. Recuento de exámenes 1, lecturas lógicas 63, lecturas físicas 0, lecturas anticipadas 0, lecturas lógicas de LOB 0, lecturas físicas de LOB 0, lecturas anticipadas de LOB 0.
Tabla 'tabla1'. Recuento de exámenes 1, lecturas lógicas 64, lecturas físicas 0, lecturas anticipadas 0, lecturas lógicas de LOB 0, lecturas físicas de LOB 0, lecturas anticipadas de LOB 0.

(1 fila afectada)

Tiempos de ejecución de SQL Server:
   Tiempo de CPU = 562 ms, tiempo transcurrido = 616 ms.

Hasta aquí, se bien claro que a igualdad de info, numeros mayores peor.

```
set statistics time, io on

SELECT A.* FROM DBO.MITABLAG2 A INNER JOIN TABLA1 T ON A.ID= T.ID
UNION 
SELECT A.* FROM DBO.MITABLAG2 A INNER JOIN TABLA2 T ON A.ID= T.ID
UNION 
SELECT A.* FROM DBO.MITABLAG2 A INNER JOIN TABLA3 T ON A.ID= T.ID
UNION 
SELECT A.* FROM DBO.MITABLAG2 A INNER JOIN TABLA4 T ON A.ID= T.ID
UNION 
SELECT A.* FROM DBO.MITABLAG2 A INNER JOIN TABLA5 T ON A.ID= T.ID

set statistics time, io off
```

Ahora la query la enlazo con la tabla grande tabla por tabla, y aunque yo pienso como humano que el retorno debiera de ser peor, para estos datos de este ejemplo resulta que no, es bastante mejor.

(0 filas afectadas)
Tabla 'miTablaG2'. Recuento de exámenes 0, lecturas lógicas 76605, lecturas físicas 0, lecturas anticipadas 0, lecturas lógicas de LOB 0, lecturas físicas de LOB 0, lecturas anticipadas de LOB 0.
Tabla 'tabla5'. Recuento de exámenes 1, lecturas lógicas 64, lecturas físicas 0, lecturas anticipadas 0, lecturas lógicas de LOB 0, lecturas físicas de LOB 0, lecturas anticipadas de LOB 0.
Tabla 'tabla4'. Recuento de exámenes 1, lecturas lógicas 64, lecturas físicas 0, lecturas anticipadas 0, lecturas lógicas de LOB 0, lecturas físicas de LOB 0, lecturas anticipadas de LOB 0.
Tabla 'tabla3'. Recuento de exámenes 1, lecturas lógicas 65, lecturas físicas 0, lecturas anticipadas 0, lecturas lógicas de LOB 0, lecturas físicas de LOB 0, lecturas anticipadas de LOB 0.
Tabla 'tabla2'. Recuento de exámenes 1, lecturas lógicas 63, lecturas físicas 0, lecturas anticipadas 0, lecturas lógicas de LOB 0, lecturas físicas de LOB 0, lecturas anticipadas de LOB 0.
Tabla 'tabla1'. Recuento de exámenes 1, lecturas lógicas 64, lecturas físicas 0, lecturas anticipadas 0, lecturas lógicas de LOB 0, lecturas físicas de LOB 0, lecturas anticipadas de LOB 0.

(1 fila afectada)

Tiempos de ejecución de SQL Server:
   Tiempo de CPU = 94 ms, tiempo transcurrido = 168 ms.

En conclusión, si eres capaz de analizar un plan de ejecución solo el motor te dirá lo que hace y como lo hace. Pero si todavía no, puedes utilizar las estadisticas de consumo de recursos y estas te ayudarán a entender que resultado es el mejor para tus datos y tu modelo de tablas.

No obvies lo que te han comentado y prueba también con UNION ALL y en la salida puedes hacer un distinct o un group by. Muchas maneras posibles de obtener lo mismo.

Espero te ayude